# System requirements of Tor Relay (How powerful a CPU and RAM should I use)

Tags: configuration

I read all documentation and FAQ at Tor project website, but cant find obvious information about "System requirements of Tor Relay" except bandwidth...

For example, I would like run a relay tor node for about "60-80Mbit/s" total bandwidth so I want to know what power the processor and RAM should I use. How many core(-s), GHz, MBytes of RAM for server that will be able to push 60-80Mbit/s? Approximately? Please share your experience.

Regards

Comment: https://www.ovh.com/us/vps/vps-ssd.xml I use VPS SSD 1 and it works perfectly, never crashed. And it's not using 100% of CPU or RAM. The fact that it's and SSD is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled over a mailing list that exactly treated this issue.

[How to Run High Capacity Tor Relays](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-relays/2010-August/000164.html)

Answer (score 0):

My setup for my Tor Relay is a Raspberry PI1. It has a Minibian (with not much packages) on it and I configured it with ~360MB of RAM for the Tor relay. My Bandwith is about 1Mbit.

Hope I could help you.

Comment: Is it still the case? It seems Tor demands much more RAM these days.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi is handling it Fine. The **main requrement** for Linux-based relay is the very last mainline kernel from kernel.org's Git and properly configured + Tor libraries compiled with *-mtune=native*, the libraries are :

- OpenSSL - official git repo is [here](http://openssl.org/source/gitrepo.html)
- libevent - official GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/libevent/libevent)

UPDATE: Of course, RPi won't give you 60-80Mbit/s, You will need a motherboard with two ethernet interfaces already on board(for a case of personal privacy router), or - for a "minimal requirement" - PCI-E v3 and a very good server NIC, like [this](http://www.intel.eu/content/www/eu/en/ethernet-products/gigabit-server-adapters/ethernet-server-adapter-i350.html) or similar : the cheap NIC for WAN/Internet will make an interrupt storm and steal your CPU power. RAM is about to be as fast as hell, but you need just 1-2 Gigabytes - in case of tor you will never have a need in the big amount of memory! Do not use single module - don't forget a dual-channel mode benefits! So 2 modules of AMD Radeon DDR3-2400 will be just fine. CPU must have AES hardware acceleration and a good clock speed : Tor's single-core crypto nowdays is a problem, so I do recommend a 2-core CPU with the highest clock and FSB speed. Storage does not matter at all - you can easily utilize a zram/zswap and tmpfs for all the things your relay will ever need, booting from a read-only flash memory. For a hardware spec proposal:

- Motherboard [MSI (ecx-cdw-us-3882756) Micro ATX AMD A88X](http://shop.amd.com/en-us/components/motherboards/ecxcdwus3882756)
- CPU/APU [AMD A10-Series APU A10-7890K](http://shop.amd.com/en-us/components/processors/AD789KXDJCHBX)
- Memory [AMD Radeon™ R9 Gamer Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3 2400 MHz CL11](http://www.radeonmemory.com/pdf/R938G2401U1K_R9_2400_8GB_kit_Spec_Sheet.pdf)

Comment: Are you sure about Mbytes, not MBytes? Look like too strong conf.

Comment: @KilosNoodlas you can take dualcore CPU but 4GHz+ is strongly recomended : after 15-20 you will see a bottleneck in single-core crypto, so the FSB+Ram speed+Core clock will play a significant role.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your reply.
My goal is calculate system requirements for 60-80 Mbit per second (Or so).

I have experience with RPi, and it is too low bandwidth through them, cuz they have weak processor. That why I would like start my new relay on dedicated server with more bandwidth, but idk which configuration server should I buy (Just cheap home PC).

Comment: please take a look at my answer update